# Python to Read Multiple Nested JSON into Canonical form

Tags: python, json, pandas, canonicalization

[image: Sample Data]

In this attached picture, I need to fetch the VALUE in each ZIP code. This has to be done using python. In this image, I wanted to fetch the underlined values as below:

[image: Expected Output]

Can anyone please confirm? I am pretty new to Python.

One blockage here is, there can be multiple nested levels inside this Address-Zip. In the attachment, we have Zip5, Zip4 inside Zip. Similarly we may have Zip1, Zip2, Zip3 etc. to any levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code
import json

```
#load json from file
with open('path_to_file/person.json', 'r') as f:
  data = json.load(f)

for item in data:
    print(item['Zip']['value']['Zip5']['0']['value'])
```

You can use recursive function like this:

```
def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for k, v in json_input.items():
            if k == lookup_key:
                yield v
            else:
                yield from item_generator(v, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My bad, I missed it. I will need a dynamic FOR LOOP or any loop. Since I have multiple NETSED Loops for many attributes. The one pasted here is just one Attribute with small level of nested.